# Filled curved in legend entry - tikz/pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend, fill

I am trying to make a simple plot in `pgfplots` that consists of a curve with a filled area below it and vertical dashed lines that divide the area below the curve in sections. A simple output can be produced with the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}    

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[domain=0:5,
                     xmin=0, xmax=5,
                     ymin=0, ymax=1,
                     axis on top,
                 samples=100,
                 xlabel={time (sec)},
                 ylabel={$dP/dt$},
                 axis line style={line width=1pt}]
    \addplot+[mark=none, solid, ultra thick, color=black, fill = black, fill opacity=0.2] {exp(-x)}\closedcycle;\addlegendentry{$R=1Hz$};         
    \addplot[no markers, color=black, domain=0:1, samples=100, dashed, thick, area legend] {exp(-x)} \closedcycle;\addlegendentry{Relative probability}
    \addplot[color=black, domain=1:2, samples=100, dashed, thick] {exp(-x)} \closedcycle;
    \addplot[color=black, domain=2:3, samples=100, dashed, thick] {exp(-x)} \closedcycle;
    \addplot[color=black, domain=3:4, samples=100, dashed, thick] {exp(-x)} \closedcycle;
    \addplot[color=black, domain=4:5, samples=100, dashed, thick] {exp(-x)} \closedcycle;
    \addplot[mark=none, black, <-] coordinates {(0.55,0.61) (0.55,0.85)};
    \addplot[mark=none, black, <-] coordinates {(1.55,0.23) (1.55,0.47)};
    \addplot[mark=none, black, <-] coordinates {(2.55,0.092) (2.55,0.332)};
    \addplot[mark=none, black, <-] coordinates {(3.55,0.040) (3.55,0.28)};
    \addplot[mark=none, black, <-] coordinates {(4.55,0.021) (4.55,0.261)};
    \pgfplotsset{
        after end axis/.code={
            \node[above] at (axis cs:0.55,0.85){\small{$63\%$}};   
            \node[above] at (axis cs:1.55,0.47){\small{$23\%$}};
            \node[above] at (axis cs:2.55,0.332){\small{$8.6\%$}};
            \node[above] at (axis cs:3.55,0.28){\small{$3.1\%$}};
            \node[above] at (axis cs:4.55,0.261){\small{$1.2\%$}}; 
    }
}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What I am trying to do is to modify the legend in a way that the dashed square will be filled in with gray, i.e. the fill colour of the curve.

I thought that using `no markers` and `area legend` inside the `\addplot[]` command arguments would do the trick but I wasn't lucky!

Any idea on how to fill the dashed square in the legend?

Comment: I was going to add an answer, but Phelype beat me to it, so I'll mention this here: That last `\pgfplotsset{ after end axis...` thing seems unnecessarily complicated, why don't you just append the nodes at the end of the plots that draw the arrows, e.g. `\addplot[black, <-] coordinates {(0.55,0.61) (0.55,0.85)} 
 node[above,font=\small] {$63\%$};`. Note also that `\small` is not a macro that takes an argument, it's a switch that influences the following text, so should be used as `{\small text}`, not `\small{text}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. : Thank you very much for your comment and suggestions. Since I think your suggestions are valid and important, could you provide an answer so as to be kept as a future reference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(As requested in a comment.)

I had the same idea as Phelype, `\addlegendimage`, for solving what you actually asked about.

The code below has some other simplifications as well. Instead of five plots with `\closedcycle` to generate the vertical dashed lines, I use a single `\addplot [ycomb, ..]` to do so. This works in this case, but might not look good in other cases.

Further, the use of `\pgfplotsset{after end axis...` to add the nodes is unnecessarily complicated. First of all, you don't need the `\pgfplotsset` at all, just add `\node[above] at (axis cs:0.55,0.85){\small{$63\%$}};` directly in the axis environment.

But note that a `node` can be appended to the end of an `\addplot coordinates {...}`, so doing

```
\addplot[black, <-] coordinates {(0.55,0.61) (0.55,0.85)}
      node[above,font=\small] {$63\%$};
```

instead seems more convenient.  Note also that `\small` is not a macro that takes an argument, it's a switch that influences the following text in the same group, so should be used as `{\small text}`, not `\small{text}`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots} % also loads tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}    

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[domain=0:5,
                     xmin=0, xmax=5,
                     ymin=0, ymax=1,
                     axis on top,
                 samples=100,
                 xlabel={time (sec)},
                 ylabel={$dP/dt$},
                 axis line style={line width=1pt}
]

    % not saying this is better or worse, but you can make do with fewer settings
    \addplot [ultra thick, black, fill, fill opacity=0.2] {exp(-x)} \closedcycle;
    \addlegendentry{$R=1Hz$};

    % add custom legend entry
    \addlegendimage{area legend,dashed, thick,fill = black, fill opacity=0.2}
    \addlegendentry{Relative probability}

    % use ycomb to draw the vertical dashed lines
    \addplot[black, dashed, thick, ycomb, samples at={0,...,5}] {exp(-x)};

    \addplot[black, <-] coordinates {(0.55,0.61) (0.55,0.85)}
          node[above,font=\small] {$63\%$};
    \addplot[black, <-] coordinates {(1.55,0.23) (1.55,0.47)}
          node[above,font=\small] {$23\%$};
    \addplot[black, <-] coordinates {(2.55,0.092) (2.55,0.332)}
          node[above,font=\small] {$8.6\%$};
    \addplot[black, <-] coordinates {(3.55,0.040) (3.55,0.28)}
          node[above,font=\small] {$3.1\%$};
    \addplot[black, <-] coordinates {(4.55,0.021) (4.55,0.261)}
          node[above,font=\small] {$1.2\%$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Addendum

You can do the arrows more automated if you want to, with a loop. One of the possible approaches is demonstrated in the code below, which results in this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots} % also loads tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}    

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[domain=0:5,
                     xmin=0, xmax=5,
                     ymin=0, ymax=1,
                     axis on top,
                 samples=100,
                 xlabel={time (sec)},
                 ylabel={$dP/dt$},
                 axis line style={line width=1pt}
]

    % not saying this is better or worse, but you can make do with fewer settings
    \addplot [ultra thick, black, fill, fill opacity=0.2] {exp(-x)} \closedcycle;
    \addlegendentry{$R=1Hz$};

    % add custom legend entry
    \addlegendimage{area legend,dashed, thick,fill = black, fill opacity=0.2}
    \addlegendentry{Relative probability}

    % use ycomb to draw the vertical dashed lines
    \addplot[black, dashed, thick, ycomb, samples at={0,...,5}] {exp(-x)};

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5}{ % insert the x-values where you want arrows
       \addplot [<-, shorten <=2pt] coordinates {(#1,{exp(-#1)})(#1,{exp(-#1) + 0.24})}
          node[above,font=\small] {%
            \pgfmathparse{exp(-#1)*100}%
            $\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=1]{\pgfmathresult}\%$};
    }


    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: However they are all very nice works. I have voted everybody +1.

Answer (score 7):

One possibility is to define a custom `\addlegendimage`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}    

\pgfplotsset{
    legend image with text/.style={
        legend image code/.code={%
            \draw [#1,yshift=-0.5ex] (0,0) rectangle (4ex,1.5ex);
        }
    },
}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[domain=0:5,
                     xmin=0, xmax=5,
                     ymin=0, ymax=1,
                     axis on top,
                 samples=100,
                 xlabel={time (sec)},
                 ylabel={$dP/dt$},
                 axis line style={line width=1pt}]
                 %axis lines=left]  
    \addplot+[mark=none, solid, ultra thick, color=black, fill = black, fill opacity=0.2] {exp(-x)}\closedcycle;\addlegendentry{$R=1Hz$};
    \addlegendimage{legend image with text={fill, color=black, dashed, thick, fill opacity=0.2}} \addlegendentry{Relative probability}
    \addplot[color=black, domain=1:2, samples=100, dashed, thick] {exp(-x)} \closedcycle;
    \addplot[color=black, domain=2:3, samples=100, dashed, thick] {exp(-x)} \closedcycle;
    \addplot[color=black, domain=3:4, samples=100, dashed, thick] {exp(-x)} \closedcycle;
    \addplot[color=black, domain=4:5, samples=100, dashed, thick] {exp(-x)} \closedcycle;
    \addplot[mark=none, black, <-] coordinates {(0.55,0.61) (0.55,0.85)};
    \addplot[mark=none, black, <-] coordinates {(1.55,0.23) (1.55,0.47)};
    \addplot[mark=none, black, <-] coordinates {(2.55,0.092) (2.55,0.332)};
    \addplot[mark=none, black, <-] coordinates {(3.55,0.040) (3.55,0.28)};
    \addplot[mark=none, black, <-] coordinates {(4.55,0.021) (4.55,0.261)};
    \pgfplotsset{
        after end axis/.code={
            \node[above] at (axis cs:0.55,0.85){\small{$63\%$}};   
            \node[above] at (axis cs:1.55,0.47){\small{$23\%$}};
            \node[above] at (axis cs:2.55,0.332){\small{$8.6\%$}};
            \node[above] at (axis cs:3.55,0.28){\small{$3.1\%$}};
            \node[above] at (axis cs:4.55,0.261){\small{$1.2\%$}}; 
    }
}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]